# How can I tell Solr to return the hit search terms per document?

Tags: solr, term-document-matrix

I have a question about queries in Solr. When I perform a query with multiple search terms that are all logically linked by OR (e.g. `q=content:(foo OR bar OR foobar)`) than Solr returns a list of documents that all matches any of these terms. But what Solr does *not* return is which documents were hit by which term(s). So in the example above, what I want to know is which documents in my result list contains the term *foo* etc. Given this information I would be able to create a term-document matrix.

So my question is: how can I tell Solr to give me that missing piece of information? I'm sure it is somewhere, otherwise the search as a whole would not work. But what am I missing? Thanks for your help.

PS: As a workaround I'm performing a single Solr query for all the search terms. But as you can imagine it's a desaster in matters of performance as the number of search terms can exceed 50 :(

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Kind of depends on your requirements, but as far as I know there is no specific support for this in Solr. You can however hack it together in a few other ways. Not sure what you can expect for performance for these, tho..

**Use Highlightning**

If you use highlighting you can parse the returned highlighted snippets for the start/end tags of the highlighted text. This will be the term that matched something in your query.

**Use debugQuery Information**

You can parse the information returned by a query with `debugQuery=true` to determine that a term was associated with a result by looking at `termWeight` (iirc). This might be a filtered version of your original term (if you have stemming etc. active for the field).

**Use Field Collapsing**

By using group.query you can build lists of documents that matches each term, instead of issuing several requests. You can also build queries that feature several of the terms OR-ed together if you need lists for "contains either". Might not be effective for a large amount of fields.

**Parse the returned document yourself**

Get the document, then extract the terms by yourself. Will require a bit of fuzzy matching, since you'll have to deal with text processing on the Solr side as well.

**Use Function Queries**

You can get metavalues for each document with each term from a FunctionQuery that looks up the number occurences of a term in that document. Will require quite a few function queries for a large number of terms, but might be fast.

.. neither option is perfect, but might work for the problem at hand.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply and the interesting suggestions. I now use the Function Queries and it seems that performance is not an issue :) For those who are interested: I'm using the`exists` function and add a pseudo field for every search term like so: `fl=exists(query({!v='content:(foo)'})),exists(query({!v='content:(bar)'}))`. From the response I parse the search term with an Regex.

Comment: @tbmsu Would you mind posting that as an answer? I think it helps round out the post. Also note that you can alias pseudo fields to avoid the regex parsing, e.g. `fl=foo:exists(query({!v='content:(foo)'}))`

Comment: Is there any solution I could list all index of a field of a given document?

Comment: @Shih-EnChou Comments are not the place to ask new questions - create a question for that. To see the raw tokens for a document, use the LukeRequestHandler to get it in Solr or the Luke tool to inspect the index files outside of Solr.

Answer (score 10):

My comment as an answer:

I use the Function Queries and it seems that performance is not an issue :) For those who are interested: I'm using the`exists` function and add a pseudo field for every search term like so: `fl=exists(query({!v='content:(foo)'})),exists(query({!v='content:(bar)'}))`. From the response I parse the search term with an Regex.

As Paul stated above, you can alias pseudo fields to avoid the regex parsing, e.g. `fl=foo:exists(query({!v='content:(foo)'}))`

Comment: This is useful to me, thanks. Can you please let me know how i add more than one condition to this local param? i tried `fl=foo:exists(query({!v='content:(foo) and content2:(foo2)'})). I tried some variations to it as well, but does not seem to work. Any idea?

Comment: Sorry posted bit too early guess, `and` has to be in capital to make this to work. Otherwise it treats as a string i guess

Answer (score 0):

In my case `solr6.6` the query `fl=foo:exists(query({!v='content:(foo)'}))` not seems to be working it always return **0** documents and I was having `foo` in my document so I need to change this query to `?q=*:*&fl=foo:exists(query({!v='content:(foo)'}))` and I started work for me.

Comment: The reason for that is that you _didn't include a query_. `fl` is not a query - it's just an instruction to Solr telling it what fields it should return. You'll have to include a query as you discovered, where `q=*:*` would return all documents in the collection.