# Solr - How to get overlap counts of each result with query terms?

Tags: solr, lucene, solr4

I want to compute overlap counts (how many of the query terms are found in the specified document) for each document in search result.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I tell Solr to return the hit search terms per document?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25038080/how-can-i-tell-solr-to-return-the-hit-search-terms-per-document)

Comment: Not quite sure what your trying to accomplish here.  Usually that information is accessed by the [Similarity](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_10_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/Similarity.html), where it is readily accessible to the [`coord` method](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_10_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/Similarity.html#coord(int,%20int)).  Does having it in that context work for what you need?

Comment: Thanks @femtoRgon, Yes, I want to sort search result using overlap counts and then using doc score.