# Term count in solr result set

Tags: python, apache, solr

I am looking to return the search term hit count through the solr result object when I fire off a query to solr. I have tried using the term vector option in the solrconfig however this has not returned the count back.

I am using pysolr to fire off the requests from my django site, I have written a method in python to do the term count based on the number of  tags returned in the highlighting sections of the results object. However this does not scale very well (using regex against millions of document results) hence why I am looking for an alternative solution.

I expect solr to return a dictionary of some kind with the document as the key and the term count as the value, something similar to how it returns highlighted values. If this is possible, what would i need to edit in the solrconfig? If not, is there a better way to do a term count other than using regex?

Current functions doing the count-

```
comp_doc = []
for k, v in results.iteritems():
            reg = re.findall('<em class="highlighting">(.*?)</em>', str(v.values()).lower())
            counter = dict(Counter(reg))
            comp_dict = {}
            comp_dict['terms'] = counter
            comp_dict['key'] = k
            comp_doc.append(comp_dict)
return comp_doc
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Are you looking for which terms that produced a hit, or the count of each term in the resulting document? In either case, [How can I tell Solr to return the hit search terms per document?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25038080/how-can-i-tell-solr-to-return-the-hit-search-terms-per-document) might help.