# SOLR: Return missing words for multi word searches

Tags: search, solr, lucene

I'm trying to receive the words of a search query in solr, which were not included in a match.
Let's say I'm searching for "Red Hat Linux chickpeas" (without quotes) and one of the hits is "Red Hat Enterprise Linux operating system".. Then I'd like to get the information that the word "chickpeas" is missing in this result.

I think this should somehow be possible with SOLR, however apparently I couldn't come up with the right google/stackoverflow query to find a solution to this.

Comment: Is your search with quotes("), coz then it is a exact match. Else it will search for these keywords.

Comment: so, for every doc you want to know which terms are missing from the initial query, correct?

Comment: @Mysterion yes, this is correct

Comment: @user1211 No, the query is without the quotes

Comment: In query set debug =  true and you can extract information from results. My 2 cents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my question is using an exists function query for each search term.

See here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26163945/467944

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a facet to get the number returns with the given terms:

```
q=Red+Hat+Linux+chickpeas&facet=true&facet.field={!terms=red,hat,linux,chickpeas}text
```

Where text is a catch-all field (tokenized, lowercase filtered). Note that the facets are case-sensitive.

Comment: but that would give me the overall view on what's the count of each word in all the searchresult. What I'd like to have is a view on each single result.