# How to get how many list of terms exists in specific document in apache solr

Tags: search, solr

I have a situation in which I have a list of words and I want to match them with a specific document field.

Suppose I have list `[apple, orange, mango]` and have document in which I have `apple is a good food as compared to mango` now I want my search query should return `apple` and `mango` because they exist/match with the document.

Is there any built-in function or any way I can do that could be pragmatically or using query ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I tell Solr to return the hit search terms per document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25038080/how-can-i-tell-solr-to-return-the-hit-search-terms-per-document)

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to get this information by turning hit highlighting in your query and looking at the [highlighting information in the response](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_0/highlighting.html). It won't be a one-to-one match as the highlighting information considers stemming and you might see variations of the words that you searched for (e.g. `apples` instead of `apple`, or `running` instead of `run`) but this might get you somewhat close to what you are looking for.